# Flutter: set tabindex using Backbutton function like in twitter with bottomnavigationbar?

Tags: dart, flutter

is it possible to use OnWillpopScope to be like the twitter app when your in a different tab when you press back it returns home or the tabindex gets or sets to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done using [TabController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController-class.html). It has a method [`animateTo()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabController/animateTo.html) which can be used in the `onWillPop` callback of the [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget.

Here is an example implementation

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<Widget> _tabs = <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
  ];
  TabController _tabController;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

   @override  
   dispose(){
      _tabController.dispose();
      super.dispose();


   }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        _tabController.animateTo(0);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: _tabs.toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if I am on another screen and then back it to TabBar screen that time I want to switch tab ? [ for ex. : I have two tabs "One" and "Two" if I pressed on tab Two then it navigates to another screen and then from this screen when I do back-press then I want to show tab "Two" not tab "One" ? ]