# How to use android back button to navigate to a page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `bottomNavigationBar` in my app with 3 screens in it. I want that whenever I press back button on my android/ios phone, I traverse back to my first page/screen of `bottomNavigationBar`. I don't have in-app back button on other two pages. So, one can only go back by pressing phone's own back button. And if someone uses them on other two screens, I want to send the user to first screen of the `bottomNavigationBar`.

Take these pictures for reference -

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I am on Practice or Profile Screen, and I press my phone's back button, then I should land on learn page. How should I achieve this? Is WillPopScope useful here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go to the previous Tab when the Device Back Button is pressed in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350252/how-to-go-to-the-previous-tab-when-the-device-back-button-is-pressed-in-flutter)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274920/flutter-set-tabindex-using-backbutton-function-like-in-twitter-with-bottomnavig

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61622795/back-button-leads-to-a-very-first-page

Comment: @OMiShah nah, first one is not helping out and other two are for tab bar. I am having problem with bottom navgationbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WillPopScope` to achieve this.

Wrap the whole screen in `WillpopScope` this help you to trigger an event when you press a backbouuton.

```
onWillPop: () async {
        return 
           // Do something.
      },
```

**Refer the example below :-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool shouldPop = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return shouldPop;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Flutter WillPopScope demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              OutlinedButton(
                child: const Text('Push'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push<void>(
                    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return const MyStatefulWidget();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              OutlinedButton(
                child: Text('shouldPop: $shouldPop'),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(
                    () {
                      shouldPop = !shouldPop;
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              const Text('Push to a new screen, then tap on shouldPop '
                  'button to toggle its value. Press the back '
                  'button in the appBar to check its behavior '
                  'for different values of shouldPop'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this package - back_button_interceptor: ^5.0.2.
You can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor)

It is pretty simple to use. Just make the function -

```
    bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
    print("BACK BUTTON!"); // Do some stuff.
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = 0;
    });
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Where, _selectedIndex  is used for control index of navigation bar.